# I have a listview which is being populated using firebase but i get error when i try to switch activity on clicking on the listview item?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-realtime-database

my code for the lsitView activity

```
public class FriendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FloatingActionButton fab;
private DatabaseReference mRef;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ArrayList<String> frnList;
public String reciever;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_friend, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        loadLoginView();
        return true;
    }
    else
     {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);

    frnList = new ArrayList<>();

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadLoginView();
            }
        }
    };


    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addFriend);
    final ListView friendList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.friendList);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(FriendActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, frnList);
    friendList.setAdapter(adapter);

    mRef.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("friends").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            try {
                friend frn = dataSnapshot.getValue(friend.class);
                String em = frn.getEmail();
                frnList.add(em);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FriendActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage(String.valueOf(e))
                        .setPositiveButton("Ok!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            friend remfrn = dataSnapshot.getValue(friend.class);
            adapter.remove(remfrn.getEmail());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(FriendActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_friend_layout);
            Button btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addFriendFromDialog);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    TextView tv = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.friend);
                    String email = tv.getText().toString();
                    if (email.length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            addFriendToList(email);
                            Toast.makeText(FriendActivity.this, "ButtonListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FriendActivity.this);
                            builder.setTitle("ERROR")
                                    .setMessage(String.valueOf(e));
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            dialog.show();

        }
    });



    friendList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            reciever = frnList.get(i);
            Intent intent = new    Intent(FriendActivity.this,MainActivity.class)
startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


private void addFriendToList(String email) {

    //final String[] emailId = email.split("@");
    friend frn = new friend();
    frn.setEmail(email);
    mRef.child("users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("friends").push().setValue(frn);
    Toast.makeText(FriendActivity.this, "adding", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    /*mRef.child("friends"+mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Toast.makeText(FriendActivity.this,"valueEventListener",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(!(dataSnapshot.exists())){
                adapter.add(emailId[0] + "@" + emailId[1]);
                Toast.makeText(FriendActivity.this,"valueEventListener inside",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });*/

}

public void loadLoginView() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(FriendActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

log cat of the error being displayed

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.shubhamchauhan.firebasepractice, PID: 21158
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method     'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2344)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1864)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1659)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15636)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4967)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5786)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Note :

it seems to be a problem with the list being populated from firebase because when i switch off the internet connection and then click on the list item the intent just works fine?

Comment: i cannot see your error clearly

Comment: yeah, that's precisely what i am saying too.. I mean wheres the error actually occurring? and yeah did you have a look at the note (thought it would help).